# Insert into table from query result error ERROR at line 1: ORA-00913: too many values

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Hi can someone help on how to figure this out? I'm getting the error:

> ERROR at line 1:ORA-00913: too many values

since columns to be inserted in another table is equal. I've searched other sites and follow their instruction on how to insert result of query to another table

```
INsert into GLOBE_BILLING_REPORT
(BILL_YEAR, 
BILL_MONTH,
ACCT_NO,
EMP_ID, 
ASSIGNEE, 
DESIGNATION, 
TERR_NUM, 
JDEID, 
MOBILE_NO,
BILL_NUM,
BILL_TYPE, 
CREDIT_LIMIT, 
PLAN_ID,
BALANCE, 
PAYMENTS,
CREDITS_PRIOR_ADJ,  
OVERDUE,
MSF, 
OTHER_CHARGES, 
DEBIT_ADJ, 
CREDIT_ADJ, 
LOCAL_DATA, 
NDD, 
IDD, 
ROAM, 
SMS, 
GPRS, 
WIS_USAGE, 
LOADING_CHARGES, 
VAT, 
OCT_DATA, 
CURRENT_CHARGES, 
TOTAL_AMOUNT_DUE, 
DUMMY_COST_CENTRE, 
CERPS_ACCNT_CODE,
ACCNT_CODE_FOR_MSF, 
MSF_PLAN,
TAG)
Select
EMP_DATA.YEAR_DATA,   
EMP_DATA.MONTH_DATA,
EMP_DATA.ACCNT_NUM,
EMP_DATA.EMPID_DATA,
GLOBE_BILLING.ASSIGNEE,
EMP_DATA.DESIGNATION,
EMP_DATA.TERR_NUM,
EMP_DATA.JDEID,
GLOBE_BILLING.MOBILE_NO,
GLOBE_BILLING.BILL_NO,
GLOBE_BILLING.BILL_TYPE,
GLOBE_BILLING.CREDIT_LIMIT,
GLOBE_BILLING.PLAN_ID,
GLOBE_BILLING.BALANCE,
GLOBE_BILLING.PAYMENTS,
GLOBE_BILLING.CREDITS_PRIOR_ADJ,
GLOBE_BILLING.OVERDUE,
GLOBE_BILLING.MSF,
GLOBE_BILLING.OTHER_CHARGES,
GLOBE_BILLING.DEBIT_ADJ,
GLOBE_BILLING.CREDIT_ADJ,
GLOBE_BILLING."LOCAL",
GLOBE_BILLING.NDD,
GLOBE_BILLING.IDD,
GLOBE_BILLING.ROAM,
GLOBE_BILLING.SMS,
GLOBE_BILLING.GPRS,
GLOBE_BILLING.WIS_USAGE,
GLOBE_BILLING.LOADING_CHARGES,
GLOBE_BILLING.VAT,
GLOBE_BILLING."OCT",
GLOBE_BILLING.CURRENT_CHARGES,
GLOBE_BILLING.TOTAL_AMOUNT_DUE,
EMP_DATA.DUMMY_COST_CENTRE,
EMP_DATA.CERPS_ACCNT_CENTRE,
EMP_DATA.ACCNT_CODE_FOR_MSF,
EMP_DATA.MSF_PLAN,
EMP_DATA.DEPARTMENT_TAG,
EMP_DATA.STATUS
From
EMP_DATA Inner Join
GLOBE_BILLING On EMP_DATA.ACCNT_NUM = GLOBE_BILLING.ACCT_NO And
EMP_DATA.MONTH_DATA = GLOBE_BILLING.BILL_MONTH And EMP_DATA.YEAR_DATA =
GLOBE_BILLING.BILL_YEAR Where
EMP_DATA.STATUS Like '%ned%';
```

Comment: your trying to insert 39 fields ( your select ) into 38 fields ( value list )

Comment: Just read the error message...it says exactly where is the problém...you are inserting too many values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's cause your `INSERT` specifying 38 columns whereas `SELECT` is specifying 39 columns and looks like `EMP_DATA.STATUS` is extra in `SELECT` query.

Comment: OW!! THANK YOU SOO MUCH!! I DIDNT SEE THAT COMING!!